# How to make my own warnings appear in the Eclipse Problems view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am developing a CDT plug-in for Eclipse IDE. I want my own warning to appear in the Problems view.

[image]

Furthermore, my warning message is very important and must be seen by user, but Problems view may be even not shown, so I show a message box.

How can I add my warning to the Problems view and what is the preferred way to deal with warnings that must be seen in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: The Problems view shows [Markers](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "must be seen"?   Bear in mind that your users may have a different idea than you about the urgency of a message from your plugin, and that we ALL hate popups.

Comment: @CPerkins agreed, I am interested in less intrusive way to warn user than a popup, but more explicit than showing warning in a problem view. It was a hard time for one of our users to find out the problem, warning message would be nice for him.

Comment: @greg-449, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> preferred way to deal with warnings that must be seen in Eclipse IDE?

Make them errors instead of warnings.

Then, when the next state in the workflow needs the output of the problematic code, that is when it is appropriate to do a pop-up. When you are coding and making changes, it is perfectly normal to have "temporary" errors/warning in your code. Pop-ups at that time would be very inconvenient. But when I proceed to launch my code or similar then I want to be warned off.

Consider the case of doing a Java launch. If there are errors in the code there is a pop-up like this:

[image]

Comment: This makes them visible only if the Problems view is visible, though.  OP seems concerned about users who don't look at the Problems view.

Comment: @CPerkins thanks for the feedback, I have expanded the answer. My previous answer was particularly terse.